# Draw route on WKInterfaceMaps Watchkit

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am unable to draw route on WKInterfaceMaps from current location to another location. I have the lat and long for the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Nope—WatchKit apps don’t have the ability to draw route on the map. If you’d like an API for that, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Why don't you use annotation as directions mark?

[image]